Django AJAX: Passing form CSFR verification without proper token attachment. Why?
I have a small Django 5.1.1 project, in which I use an AJAX request to submit form data. I'm using {% csrf_token %} and have the setup for attaching the form csrfToken to the xhr header.
Problem: The CSFR verification is SUCCESSFUL even when xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrfToken); is commented out. The AJAX request goes through and gets the response. It only fails when the {% csrf_token %} is missing.
From what I understand it should fail without the form csfrToken attached to the header. What am I missing here?
Simplified code:
<form id="form1" method="post" class="...">
 {% csrf_token %}

 <div>
  <label for="A" class=""></label>
  <input type="text" name="symbol" id="A" class="...">
 </div>

 <div>
   <button type="submit" id="submit-button"></button>
 </div>

</form>


document.getElementById('form1').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const formData = new FormData(this);
  const csrfToken = this.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;

  xhr.open('POST', '/form-submit', true);
  // xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrfToken);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
  xhr.send(formData);
});

def index_view(request):

    return HttpResponse("", status=200)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]


You are sending the form data, so then the header is not necessary, since the csrf token is in the form data.

You are sending the form data, so then the header is not necessary, since the csrf token is in the form data. Indeed, the {% csrf_token %} template tag [Django-doc] translates to a hidden HTML input element, something like:
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="---some-token---">
There is nothing special about that input element. It is just a HTML element like any other.
Your JavaScript functions encodes the entire form, so includes the item with the csrfmiddlewaretoken. Django tries to find a CSRF token in the header, and in the POST data, and here it is in the POST data.
If you would remove the setHeader and the {% csrf_token %}, it will no longer work.
A lot of times however, AJAX requests do not encode form data, but just data they collect from somewhere else, for example from data-… attributes of HTML elements. Therefore these AJAX requests, that thus don't work with a form that provides a CSRF token, need to manually set the header.
